# Unexpected EOF character error in angular form, why ?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, mean-stack, angular-reactive-forms

I have made this form using form builder in angular but it throws an error in console.

Error:

**compiler.js:1021 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Unexpected character "EOF" ("rity.value, responsible.value)" mat-raised-button color="primary">Save**

code:

```
<mat-card>
  <form [formGroup]="createForm" class="create-form">
    <mat-form-field class="field-full-width">
      <input matInput placeholder="Title" formControlName="title" #title>
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field class="field-full-width">
      <input matInput placeholder="Responsible" formControlName="responsible" #responsible>
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field class="field-full-width">
        <textarea matInput placeholder="Description" formControlName="description" #description>
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field class="field-full-width">
       <mat-select placeholder="Severity" formControlName="severity" #severity>
         <mat-option value="low">Low</mat-option>
         <mat-option value="medium">Medium</mat-option>
         <mat-option value="high">High</mat-option>
       </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-divider></mat-divider>
    <br>
    <br>
    <button mat-raised-button color="accent" routerLink="/list">Back</button>
    <button type="submit" (click)="addIssue(title.value, description.value, severity.value, responsible.value)" mat-raised-button color="primary">Save</button>
  </form>
</mat-card>
```

.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import {IssueService} from '../../../issue.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-create',
  templateUrl: './create.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./create.component.css']
})
export class CreateComponent implements OnInit {

  createForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private Issue: IssueService, private router: Router, private fb: FormBuilder) {
      this.createForm = this.fb.group({
        title: '',
        description: '',
        severity: '',
        responsible: ''
      });
  }

  addIssue(title, description, responsible, severity) {
      this.Issue.addIssue(title, description, severity, responsible).subscribe(() => {
        console.log('Issue added');
        this.router.navigate(['/list']);
      });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Comment: Can you please create the stackblitz with the issue

Comment: @yurzui I closed that but same issue

Comment: @JavascriptLover-SKT: i don't understand that.. I am beginner

Comment: @yurzui: put that in answer so i can mark as answer.. tahnks man

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this is that you forgot to close `textarea` tag.

```
 <textarea ... formControlName="description" #description></textarea>
                                                             /\
                                                             ||
                                                          add this
```

Angular follows the same restrictions that HTML specification dictates

Answer (score 0):

You made error in mat-select. You cannot create a template variable on mat-select.
I don't understand why you are passing values like this. This is not recommended approach in ReactiveForms.
Replace your html with following:

```
<mat-card>
  <form [formGroup]="createForm" class="create-form">
    <mat-form-field class="field-full-width">
      <input matInput placeholder="Title" formControlName="title">
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field class="field-full-width">
      <input matInput placeholder="Responsible" formControlName="responsible">
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field class="field-full-width">
        <textarea matInput placeholder="Description" formControlName="description">
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field class="field-full-width">
       <mat-select placeholder="Severity" formControlName="severity">
         <mat-option value="low">Low</mat-option>
         <mat-option value="medium">Medium</mat-option>
         <mat-option value="high">High</mat-option>
       </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-divider></mat-divider>
    <br>
    <br>
    <button mat-raised-button color="accent" routerLink="/list">Back</button>
    <button type="submit" (click)="addIssue()" mat-raised-button color="primary">Save</button>
  </form>
</mat-card>
```

Replace your component with following:

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

```
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import {IssueService} from '../../../issue.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-create',
  templateUrl: './create.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./create.component.css']
})
export class CreateComponent implements OnInit {

  createForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private Issue: IssueService, private router: Router, private fb: FormBuilder) {
      this.createForm = this.fb.group({
        title: '',
        description: '',
        severity: '',
        responsible: ''
      });
  }

  addIssue() {
      this.Issue.addIssue(...this.createForm.value).subscribe(() => {
        console.log('Issue added');
        this.router.navigate(['/list']);
      });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```